# Google maps not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Come up with a weird Firefox (android) browser issue and Google maps.

When I first load the page with Google maps, the asynch callback works fine, but when the page is reloaded (using the address bar reload icon), the map is not re-rendered.

Code below. Any help appreciated

Page code -

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= ... &callback=map_global.map_init" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

java script -

```
var gm=null;
glMap[DSK_VIEW]['map']=null;

var map_global = {};

map_global.map_init = function() {

  var lat = window.$map_lat;
  var lng = window.$map_lng;
  var zoom = +window.$map_zoom;
  var type=google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;   

  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)),
    zoom: zoom,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeId: type
  };

  gm=google.maps;

  glMap[DSK_VIEW].map=new gm.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap_DSK_VIEW"),mapProp);

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? (that will demonstrate the issue on my phone?)